# Custom template in Kendo UI DatePicker

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

How can I set the **custom template** of the current month in **Kendo DatePicker**.?

With the help of javascript only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the below link and explore:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/datepicker/template